# How to set Main frame in child JDialog

Tags: java, swing

I have created a class which extends `JFrame`

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
     public MyFrame()
     {
          JPanel panel = new JPanel();
               JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                    JDialog myDialog = new JDialog(MyFrame, Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);                        
                    //How can I set my MyFrame as Parent for JDialog???
               panel.add(panel2);
          add(panel);
     }
}
```

In above code I want to set MyFrame as JDialog's parent. How can I do so? I tried putting like as I have shown in my code but that gives me error.

**How can I set my MyFrame as Parent for JDialog???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the **this** keyword.

```
JDialog myDialog = new JDialog(this, Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
```

More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Side note: You shouldn't extend JFrame for no reason. You should favor composition over inheritence. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: putting **this** works but would you like to tell me why **this** refers to MyFrame not JPanel while this JDialog is created inside a JPanel?

Comment: @ColdCoder Please read the links I provided. The this keyword refers to the enclosing instance, which is the instance of MyFrame.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer and specially thanks for links. Those are really helpful. Thanks